# JavaScript let variable displays as undefined in console.log

Tags: javascript

I've been learning JS for only three weeks so far, and got stuck in a certain situation during one of my excercises. This is my code:

```
'use strict';

var positions = [
  {
    title: 'Product_Title_1',
    producer: {
      name: 'Producer_Name_1',
      deferPeriod: 10,
      lot: 3
    },
    price: 10000
  },
  {
    title: 'Product_Title_2',
    producer: {
      name: 'Producer_Name_2',
      deferPeriod: 24,
      lot: 14
    },
    price: 9200
  },
  {
    title: 'Product_Title_3',
    producer: {
      name: 'Producer_Name_3',
      deferPeriod: 5,
      lot: 1
    },
    price: 57000
  }
];

console.log('Task 1:');
console.log();


let order = 10; //declaring it here solves the problem in a way, but it is not the way it should work
let shipment;

function lotCalculator (positions, order) {

  return shipment = {
    lots: Math.ceil(order / positions.producer.lot),
    total: Math.ceil(order / positions.producer.lot) * positions.producer.lot * positions.price
  };
}

let result1 = lotCalculator (positions[1], 15);

console.log(result1);

console.log();

console.log(`Order for Product_Title_2: ${order} pcs, order lots: ${shipment.lots}, final cost ${shipment.total} Q`); //order returns undefined
```

My code does the following: it compares the number of pieces in order with the lot size; increases the number of lots to order if order size exceeds it; calculates the final cost.

My question is: how can I make the whole thing work properly without declaring the order variable before the function?

Comment: You need to figure out how to put  your code in the question.

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your question text, [not just a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1048572).

Comment: Your only use of order is in ${order} in the console.log statement. It's sufficient to declare it before the console.log.

Comment: "Scoping Rules" section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let might offer a clue. The variable would need to be declared in the same or higher scope from the console.log() function (or any function referencing the variable).

Comment: why so you have `function lotCalculator (positions, order)` and then an outer scope variable `order`? they'll conflict...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `let shipment;` use `var shipment;` instead.

Where you defined `let` prevents the variable from being used inside your function `lotCalculator`